# Awk math formula: is there a way to replace NF with the number of digit containing fields?

Tags: awk, statistics

I have a file with many rows that look like this, with three informational columns followed by many columns of data:

```
A    B    C    0.15    0.23    0.21    0.67
```

occasionally, one column will have a missing data point, filled with the words "not found", such as:

```
A    B    C    0.15    not found    0.21    0.67
```

my awk formula calculates standard deviation as:

```
awk '{ A=0; V=0; for(N=4; N<=NF; N++) A+=$N ; A/=(NF-3) ; for(N=4; N<=NF; N++) V+=(($N-A)*($N-A))/(NF-4); print sqrt(V) }' file.txt
```

However, as you can see, this formula would give an NF-3 (all columns except first 3) of 4, when there are really 3 fields with data. So the average calculation is dividing by 4 instead of 3, as is the bottom term of the variance calculation (which is n-1).

is there a way for awk to calculate only the number of digit containing fields, such that "not found" is skipped? or perhaps is it better to use R?

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `not found` with a `0` when `NF>7` before processing the record and catch the number of substitutions made (below to var `replacements`) and subtract that from the divisor:

```
awk 'NF>7 { replacements = gsub(/not found/,0) } { # your original code here }
```

Comment: Thank you, but why the use of NF>7?

Comment: @DanS `NF>7` is likely due to the fact that `not found` looks like two records.  But this solution will set the missing sample to be a sample of zero, and may not be what you want for your stats.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to count the non-numbers, and then remove that from the calculation:

```
{
    A=0;
    V=0;
    NAN=0;
    for(N=4; N<=NF; N++) {
        A+=$N;

        # Check if this is a non number
        if (! ($N ~ /^-?[0-9.]+$/))
            NAN++;
    }
    A/=(NF-3);
    if (NAN <= NF - 4) {
        for (N=4; N<=NF; N++)
            V+=(($N-A)*($N-A))/(NF-4-NAN);
        print sqrt(V)
    }
}
```

Comment: 'chr1    800     800     0.55    0.54    0.52

chr2    801     801     0.09    1       1

chr3    802     802     0.88    0.2     0.2

chr4    803     804     Not Found       0.1     0.12'

For this file, it was not working because it said there was a fatal divisioin by zero attempted. When I asked to print NAN I got the following:
1
2
3
4

Comment: I will take a look.  Best thing to do on Stackoverflow for this sort of thing, is to edit the data into your question so that everyone can see.

Comment: Looks like blank lines were the problem?  Anyways, just edited in a check for no good data on the line.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer.

First, "Not Found" should be fixed to "NotFound" in order to avoid reading it as two fields.

Second, I added a count of the number of fields with "NotFound" using gsub:

```
awk '{ A=0; V=0; for(N=4; N<=NF; N++) A+=$N ; A/=(NF-3-(gsub(/NotFound/, ""))) ; for(N=4; N<=NF; N++) V+=(($N-A)*($N-A))/(NF-4-(gsub(/NotFound/, ""))); print sqrt(V) }' file.txt
```